# grouping but not aggregating with SQL outer join, without sorting

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-order-by

I have two tables `foo` and `bar`. For every foo there are zero or more bars. It's simply enough to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to give me a result set in which each row gives me a foo plus one of its bars (or `NULL` if there are no bars associated with the foo).

But let's say I want all the results to group the foos together. Note that I don't want them aggregated; that is, I don't want all rows of foos with each primary key collapsed. If there is a foo with primary key `foo123`, I just want all the `foo123` foos to appear together. I don't want there to be, for instance, `[foo123, foo123, foo456, foo123]`; I want `[foo123, foo123, foo123, foo456]` or even `[foo456, foo123, foo123, foo123]`.

Of course I could sort by the foo primary key, but sorting seems like overkill, as I do not care the order of the foos; only that all foos with the same ID appear "grouped" together in the result set.

**Is there a more efficient way in SQL to "group likes together" based upon some criteria without sorting?**

I'm using Oracle in case that matters.

(For what it's worth, I had a "brilliant" idea of using a join with a correlated subquery so that the bars are looked up independently for each foo, but I had forgotten that I can't have a correlated subquery in the `FROM` clause.)

Comment: I think Oracle has `LATERAL JOIN` that can be used to have a correlated subquery in `FROM` clause

Comment: "*without sorting*" - that's a clear NO. The only (really: the **only**) way to get a guaranteed order of rows is to use `ORDER BY`. There is no alternative. None.

Comment: As @Peeyush suggested you can have an [`OUTER APPLY`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABDADCJ)  join. I'm not sure how that helps you here, though.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is any way to do this reliably other than:

```
ORDER BY foo.foo_primary_key
```

The reason is that, in the absence of an `ORDER BY`, the order of results returned by a `SELECT` statement are *undefined*.

There may be ways to write the query that, in your version of Oracle, will return the results grouped the way you want without using `ORDER BY` -- but that will be prone to change unexpectedly.  It would be unwise to rely on such solutions.

Comment: You can remove the "I don't believe" part.